# Fields values generated using ng-repeat is not getting while submit

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-form

Template for form submission. This page will display the form template. Initially it shows the TItle,Full Name. On clicking the 'Add Tags' link new input fields is been generated for entering tags.

On submit, the field input(story.tag) is not been included on RequestPayload

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="save()">

    <div>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="story.title" id="title" required/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="firstName">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="story.fullname" id="fullname" required/>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="Note" >
      <div ng-repeat="story in items ">
        <label>Tag {{$index+1}}:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="story.tag" id="tag" required/>
      </div>
      <a ng-click="add()">Add Tags</a>
    </div>


    <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Story</button>
</form>
```

script :- app.js

```
angular.module("getbookmarks", ["ngResource"])
.factory('Story', function ($resource) {
    var Story = $resource('/api/v1/stories/:storyId', {storyId: '@id'});
    Story.prototype.isNew = function(){
        return (typeof(this.id) === 'undefined');
    }
    return Story;
})
.controller("StoryCreateController", StoryCreateController);


function StoryCreateController($scope, Story) {

   $scope.story = new Story();

   $scope.save = function () {
      $scope.story.$save(function (story, headers) {
         toastr.success("Submitted New Story");
      });
   };
}

//add dynamic forms
 var Note = function($scope){
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.add = function () {
      $scope.items.push({ 
        inlineChecked: false,
        tag: "",
        questionPlaceholder: "foo",
        text: ""
      });
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The story object inside ng-repeat is in another scope. This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audtugyo/9/) should do what you are looking for.

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="NoteCtrl">
        <form novalidate ng-submit="save()">
            <div>
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="story.title" id="title" required/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="firstName">Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="story.fullname" id="fullname" required/>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="story in items">
                <label>Tag {{$index+1}}:</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="story.tag" required/>
            </div> <a ng-click="add()">Add Tags</a>

            <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Story</button>
        </form>
        <div ng-repeat="test in items">
            <label>Tag {{$index+1}}: {{test.tag}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The NoteController:

```
function NoteCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.story = {};
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.story.tag = $scope.items;

    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.items.push({
            inlineChecked: false,
            tag: "",
            questionPlaceholder: "foo",
            text: ""
        });
        console.log($scope.story);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. On doing like above yes it gets all the field values in the console but on RequestPayload it contain no values ie empty